# Text is cut off?

Tags: java, android, xml, string, performance

I am trying to show an alert dialog with simply two buttons. However, the text is getting cut off in the second button:

```
  new AlertDialog.Builder(this)
            .setTitle("THIS IS MY TITLE")
            .setMessage("THIS IS MY MESSAGE")

            .setPositiveButton("Why Cutoff?", null)

            .setNegativeButton("This Shows Fully", null)

            .show();
```

The positive button is cut off, whereas the negative button shows fully. Can I show both buttons? **Maybe by stacking up the buttons on top of each other?** I just want the user to be able to read my text.

Thanks,

Ruchir

Comment: You should use custom dialog for this

Comment: @Jois How? And why will custom make text not cut off? Thanks

Comment: first thing the buttons now you are using have a specific width and a specfic text size and all. You can change that using Custom dialog which will solve your problem

Comment: This is as per devices, some device cut this off and some will separate positive button and negative button into two lines and shows full text.

Answer (score 0):

Use custom dialog. Design layout, how you want to show the dialog and buttons and set layout to the dialog like below,

```
final Dialog dialog = new Dialog(context);
dialog.setContentView(R.layout.custom);
```

Checkout [this](http://www.mkyong.com/android/android-custom-dialog-example/) example to implement custom dialog